# Django multiple Many2Many relationships

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have created a model where I define a Place, which has several properties (M2M) and each property has several choices. A user is able to vote for one or more of the choices, therefore I define a M2M relationship from the choices to a user. However I do not achieve the required functionality, as the user is connected only to the choices and not to the specific place that has the choices. my model is as follows:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    StoreName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Pic=models.ImageField(upload_to="media",blank=True,null=True)
    Address=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.StoreName   

class TypeProperty(models.Model):
    Place = models.ManyToManyField(Place)
    TypePropertyName=models.CharField(max_length=42)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.TypePropertyName

class TypeChoices(models.Model):
    TypeProperty = models.ForeignKey(TypeProperty)
    TypeChoiceName=models.CharField(max_length=42)
    UserVoted=models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,null=True)
```

How can I achieve the functionality

*A **User** has voted for the **Choice** that for the specific **Place***

Answer (score 2):

From `User` you can get `TypeChoices`:

```
user_instance.typechoices_set.all()
```

Then, you can loop through each `TypeChoice` and access the `Place` queryset through the `TypeProperty` attribute:

```
typechoice_instance.TypeProperty.Place.all()
```

Then you would need to loop through each `Place` to do whatever.

Now, looking at that, it should be immediately apparent that there's some serious flaws here. The code makes no sense, and it's not readable. This is why coding conventions exist. Please give the [Python Style Guide (PEP8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) a thorough read.

In particular to your code here, attributes on a class should be all lower-case and words in the attribute's name should be separated by underscores, i.e. `store_name` NOT `StoreName`.

Then, attribute names should parallel what they represent: `Place` makes no sense for a field that will return multiple places. Name it `places` to indicate that it returns multiple items (and in particular returns a queryset rather than a model instance).

**UPDATE**

If you want that, then you need to work backwards and select the `TypeChoices`:

```
TypeChoices.objects.filter(UserVoted=some_user, TypeProperty__Place=some_place)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I will change the code to comply with the style conventions. However this does not solve my problem. I want to know which user has voted for the choice that belongs to the property of a specific place. Your code returns all the places that have the specific property, not regarding if the user has voted for the place.

Comment: Sorry to disagree again, but this returns the choices for a property of a place that a user has voted for. It will return a choice even if the user has voted for a choice that has the same property as the place we are looking for, it does not guarantee that the user has voted for the specific place. To sum up, in the model there is no connection between the choices and a place, and I wondered how I can change the model to add this functionality.